# ASP.NET MVC5 - helper acting not with model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, expression-trees

Sometimes on pages I must show some data from attributes of different object properties. A.e. when I have a class

```
class A
{
  [CustomAttribute("See me!")]
  public int B{get;set;}
}
```

and want to show data from my custom attribute, I can use smth like
`static string TitleFor<TClass, TProp>(TClass model, Expression<Func<TClass, TProp>> expression)`

and it works good. But when I want to turn it into Html helper like

`static MvcHtmlString TitleFor<TClass, TProp>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, TClass @object, Expression<Func<TClass, TProp>> expression)`

and use it
`@Html.TitleFor(default(A), (x) => default(A).B)`

I'm getting errors like *error CS1061: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TitleFor' and no accessible extension method 'TitleFor' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)* 
where *CurrentPageModel* — class, used as model on this page.

How to do it right?

Update: added `public` keyword to my function, but it not helps much — now I'm getting *CS0117: 'HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TitleFor'*

Update 2: while .DisplayFor partially served my needs, I'm still unable to do something like that for object another than model. C# not allowing to perform member access like C++ allows with `::` operator and that reduces our abilities in metadata accessing.

Comment: do you want to call it like `@Html.TitleFor(x => x.B?` ? i dont know if i'm undertanding you

Comment: Yes, but `x` is not a page model, but another type.

Comment: Have you included correct namespace (where class that contains `TitleFor` is declared) into your view?

Comment: Yes, I checked it again.